# make string of check box values array and put qoma

Tags: php, html

HTML

```
<label>Design</label><input type="checkbox" name="chk_name[]" value="design" />
<label style="width:40px;">Website</label><input type="checkbox" name="chk_name[]" value="website" />
<label>Inquire</label><input type="checkbox" name="chk_name[]" value="inquire" />
```

PHP

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST['chk_name'])) {

    foreach($_POST['chk_name'] as $val) {
        $chk = $val; checkbox.                  
        } 
    }
?>
```

All i want here that when I get array of this checkbox I get comma seperated values except the comma at the end value.

Comment: Where is your PHP code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your inputs are posted in a form (with method POST):

```
echo implode(",", $_POST['chk_name']);
```

[implode documentation](http://php.net/implode)